# What encoding is being used in this TrueType / OpenType Font?

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, opentype

I'm parsing a TTF file.
There's a name record with platform ID 1, encoding ID 29, language ID 25.

I have found references from both [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/otspec140/name) and [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6name.html) which refer to this encoding as "Slavic".

Following the usual convention then, you'd expect the encoding to be called MacSlavic, but no such encoding exists.

[Unicode.org lacks a record of this encoding also.](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/APPLE/)

Given a platform ID and encoding ID, is there a way to get the correct charset / encoding to decode the name of the font?

What is the general solution to this for all the other integer IDs?

*Edit:* I dug in to get the actual raw data, but since it's all low ASCII it doesn't really help in determining the encoding. However it might help in identifying the language, which might narrow down the range of potential encodings?

```
57 73 7a 79 73 74 6b 69 65 20 63 65 63 68 79 20   Wszystkie cechy 
74 79 70 6f 67 72 61 66 69 63 7a 6e 65            typograficzne
```

Comment: Name Records store the encoding as triplets: what's the language ID? As for how to get the correct charset: the best source for this kind of information is to look at prior art, like https://github.com/foliojs/fontkit/blob/e2ff84e69f83272a0f05179d537a86a462aea299/src/encodings.js - also, it's worth asking OpenType specific questions over on https://typerdrawers.com instead, as font engineering is such a niche topic, asking in the place where all the big names in fonts hang out is far more likely to get you a good answer, quickly.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans languageID is 25, Polish. I guess that's consistent with 29 maybe being MacCentralEuropean, if I can believe that JS implementation... although it has seemingly slightly off mappings for some things, like MacJapanese is mapped to Shift_JIS even though the docs for MacJapanese say that it is a superset. :(

Comment: The language ID shouldn't be needed to determine the characters in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Platform 1 is archaic: it was designed for the Macintosh Script Manager infrastructure that goes back to the early 1990s. For platform 1 encoding 29, that corresponds to Mac OS Central European Roman.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1399980-afp_text_encodings/ktextencodingmaccentraleurroman?language=objc

On MacOS, the [Text Encoding Conversion Manager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/carbon_core/text_encoding_conversion_manager?language=objc) APIs may be useful to you.